# Center element until it meets an obstacle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are two elements inside a container - one (blue) needs to stay to the left, and the other one (green) is centered relative to the **outer red**. However, if the screen is small enough, the centered container(green) cannot overlap with the container on the left(blue), it should always stay to the right of the blue. Any ideas how this can be accomplished? If not with css, then may be with js?

large screen

[image]

small screen

[image]

So far i got:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/16/)

```html
<div class="red">   
    <div class="blue">
        texttexttexttext
    </div>
    <div class="centered">
        Centered Container of fixed width
    </div>    
</div>
```

```css
.red {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;

}
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 70px);
    width: 140px;
    top: 0;
}
```

This centers the green container, but it overlaps with the blue on smaller screen.

Edit: added some center markings to easily see the centers

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is something that can be used in page header with items on the side and title in the middle. So, I took a very different and simpler approach. When there is not much width, viewport centering does not look good. Use media query to switch between centering mode. [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56pfra41/1)

[image]
[image]

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#center {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #center {
        position: static;
        transform: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variation of absolute centering technique:

```css
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;  /* This is the position of the collision with the obstacle */
    right: 150px; /* Same value as above, in order to center */
    margin: auto; /* This centers */
    width: 140px; /* It needs a width */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/14/)

This technique only works if the obstacle is at the left, not at the right.

Consider adding a `min-width` to the container to prevent `.centered` from overflowing it.

Comment: Bravo! Seems to be the perfect solution.

Comment: sweet! would it be possible to make it work if the blue width is uknown?

Comment: @skyisred I don't think so, unless using javascript.

Comment: @skyisred [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/17/) is probably what you need if blue width is unknown. Although in my opinion Oriol has answered your original question.

Comment: @skyisred If blue's width is unknown but won't vary, you can try http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/25/

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript,

```js
var blue = document.getElementById('blue'),
    red = document.getElementById('red'),
    centered = document.getElementById('centered');
window.onresize = function() {
    centered.style.left = Math.max(
        blue.offsetWidth,
        (red.clientWidth-centered.offsetWidth) / 2
    ) + 'px';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/18/)

Answer (score 2):

If the blue box should have a flexible width, I think the only solution is to use JavaScript.

Here's a fork of your fiddle, which changes the classes to ids and adds a window.onresize event:

http://jsfiddle.net/rf0zLpcs/

```
window.onresize= function() {
  var blue= document.getElementById('blue');
  var red=  document.getElementById('red');
  var centered= document.getElementById('centered');
  blue.style.width= Math.min(150,(red.offsetWidth-centered.offsetWidth)/2)+'px';
}
```

Comment: I think i didnt word it properly. The size of blue can change according to text or other elements inside of it, however it cannot get smaller when the screen gets smaller. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

#### As per the Best Practice:

Firstly create "two" boxes use "**float:left** or **display:inline-block** to place them in one line.

Now second step put futher content in each box and then align them accordingly.

Here is the Updated Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="yellow">
        <div class="green">Centered container</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.red {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.blue {
    float:left;
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
.yellow {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 75.5%;
    /* fallback if needed */
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    height: 100%;
}
.green {
    background-color:green;
    width :200px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### Here is the updated Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/3/

Comment: This centers the elements relative to yellow container, and the green moves away from the center of red even before it meets blue

Comment: @skyisred - Look at my answer, Its exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I updated your fiddle to show the centers of the container that need to align
http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/9/
These centers dont match

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### Demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="red large">
  <div id="centered">
    Centered container
  </div>
  <div class="blue">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 130px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
}

#centered {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: The green container gets centered relative to the white space, not the whole container. I marked element centers on your fiddle, these need to match until green meets blue
http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/10/

Answer (score 1):

Same as previous JS solution by @Oriol, just wrapped with jQuery and triggered on window load as well so it works on small screen start. (See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/24/)).

```
var $blue   = $("#blue");
var $red    = $("#red");
var $center = $("#centered");

$(window).on("load resize", function () {
    var minLeft = Math.max(
        $blue.outerWidth(), 
        ($red.outerWidth() - $center.outerWidth()) / 2
    );

    $center.css("left",  minLeft + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
.red {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
.centered{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamrul/q9u1pzb6/1/)

Comment: That is not what the OP asked for. The `div` with red border is supposed to be resized when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be this one:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="red">   
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="centered">
        Centered Container of fixed width
    </div>    
</div>
<br/>
The pink and light geen background sides mark centers of the containers. These centers should align until green container meets blue container.
```

**CSS**:

```
.red {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%,#ffe2e2 50%,#ffe2e2 100%);
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
.centered {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 73px);
    width: 140px;
    top: 0;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%,#CDF2DD 50%,#CDF2DD 100%);
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
var width = 0;
var sizeBlue = $(".blue").width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    var offset = $(".centered").offset();
    var right = $(window).width()-sizeBlue;
    if (offset.left <= sizeBlue){
        $(".centered").css("left",sizeBlue);
        width = $(window).width()-sizeBlue;
    } else if (right > width){
        $(".centered").css("left","calc(50% - 73px)");
    }
});
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/21/) how it works.

Hope it useful!

Comment: The text here centers relative to yellow container, not red container.

Comment: Exactly... U want it centered relative to the red one?

Comment: Yes plz! 
i updated fiddle to show some center markings
http://jsfiddle.net/cxbtv6z6/12/
these should align until green meets blue